# iTunes Search API returning extra, incorrect results

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, itunes-store, itunes-sdk

I've been using the iTunes API in my app for a while now, but as of the last few days I've noticed that it is returning odd results. I currently use it to search for software however it's now started adding Software Artists to the results which I believe to be incorrect with the search parameters. Below is a URL searching for my app, and below that is the returned JSON.

`http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=AppTracker%20Deluxe&limit=100&entity=software&lang=en_GB&country=GB`

```
{
"resultCount":2,
"results": [
{"kind":"software", "features":[], 
"supportedDevices":["iPhone5s", "iPadMini", "iPhone5c", "iPadFourthGen", "iPad2Wifi","iPad23G", "iPadThirdGen", "iPhone5", "iPodTouchFifthGen", "iPadThirdGen4G", "iPhone4", "iPadFourthGen4G", "iPadMini4G", "iPhone4S"], "isGameCenterEnabled":false, "
```

cutting most stuff out for space

```
"languageCodesISO2A":["EN", "FR", "DE", "IT", "ZH", "ES"], "fileSizeBytes":"3575818", "trackContentRating":"4+", "averageUserRating":5.0, "userRatingCount":5}, 
{"wrapperType":"artist", "artistType":"Software Artist", "artistName":"Handyman Interactive", "artistLinkUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/gb/artist/handyman-interactive/id586907831?uo=4", "artistId":586907831}]
}
```

As you can see, on top of returning the correct app, it is returning a software artist (myself in this case) which it hasn't done in the past. Obviously I can update the app to ignore these, but for the current version of my app it is causing slight bugs. Is this a problem down apples end or is it intended?

Thanks for the help,
Mike

Comment: Can you provide any code for this.. Actually i'm trying get game details from iTunes. But i can't get.. can you please post some code for this? My question  is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696311/get-game-details-from-itunes-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug and the behaviour is no longer present.

Mike

Comment: You should, in general follow [Postel's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) when it comes to data from remote services primarily for these issues

Comment: @Petesh I agree, but like I said, I had no way of knowing that this would ever happen and while I could have potentially handled an unexpected value better, it wouldn't have been possible to use it.